# Using cite with Elsevier article class

Tags: elsarticle, cite-package

I am trying to insert citations in my text using the `cite` package in an `elsarticle` document:

```
Classical downscaling algorithms \cite {cubic_interp, cubic_conv, lanczos} have been signal-theory based.
```

And the references are as:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{60}
\bibitem{cubic_interp}
H. S. Hou and H. C. Andrews, 
Cubic splines for image interpolation and digital filtering, IEEE Trans. Acoust., Speech, Signal Processing, vol. ASSP-26, Dec. 1978.

\bibitem{cubic_conv}
R. Keys, 
"Cubic convolution interpolation for digital image processing," in IEEE Transactions on Acoustics, Speech, and Signal Processing, vol. 29, no. 6, pp. 1153-1160, December 1981.

\bibitem{lanczos}
Duchon, C. E. 1979. 
Lanczos filtering in one and two dimensions. Journal of Applied Meteorology 18, 8.
\end{thebibliography}
```

But I cannot compile the document. The error is:

```
Runaway argument?       
]{cubic_interp, cubic_conv, lanczos} \@safe@activesfalse have been si\ETC. 
./myFile.tex:775: Paragraph ended before \org@@citex was complete 
<to be read again> \par
l.775
```

As soon as I write that line without the citations, it works. I am not sure why does this happen.

Answer (score 3):

The `elsarticle` document class automatically loads the `natbib` citation management package. Do *not* load the `cite` citation management package. You really ought to be using BibTeX and letting software create the formatted bibliography.

However, if you absolutely, positively must create the bibliography by hand, you need to supply suitably-formatted optional arguments for each `\bibitem` in order for `\citet` and `\citep` to work properly. An example is given in the code below.

[image]

I can't help but remark that the formatting is quite inconsistent across the three entries. For instance, (1) In some entries, the authors' initials come before the surnames; in others, they come after the surnames. (2) In some entries, the year is listed immediately after the authors' names, while in others the year is given at the end of the entry. (3) In one entry, the title is enclosed in quotation marks; in the other two, no quotation marks are used. To avoid such glaring formatting inconsistencies, you should take the time to learn how to set up a BibTeX database and how to run BibTeX to create the consistently-formatted bibliography.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} % numeric-style citation call-outs
\begin{document}
Classical downscaling algorithms \cite{cubic_interp, cubic_conv, lanczos} 
have been signal-theory based.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Hou and Andrews(1978)]{cubic_interp}
H. S. Hou and H. C. Andrews, Cubic splines for image interpolation and 
digital filtering, IEEE Trans. Acoust., Speech, Signal Processing, 
vol.\ ASSP-26, Dec.\ 1978.

\bibitem[Keys(1981)]{cubic_conv}
R. Keys, ``Cubic convolution interpolation for digital image processing,'' 
IEEE Transactions on Acoustics, Speech, and Signal Processing, vol.\ 29, 
no.\ 6, pp.\ 1153--1160, December 1981.

\bibitem[Duchon(1979)]{lanczos}
Duchon, C. E. 1979. Lanczos filtering in one and two dimensions. 
Journal of Applied Meteorology 18, 8.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using the `cite` package. `elsarticle` already uses the `natbib` package. Also, it is recommended to use `\citep` instead of `\cite`, as shown in the [template](http://www.elsevier.com/__data/promis_misc/elsarticle-CAG-template.zip) for Elsevier articles.

Comment: If numeric citation call-out style is in place (which is the case by default), `\citep` and `\cite` are equivalent (and `\citet` shouldn't be used).